# Docker/Wordpress: difference between bind-mounting whole wp-content folder vs. separate plugins, themes and uploads directories

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and for the last few days I've been trying to put together my "perfect local Wordpress environment". I've had some success and I think I'm moving in the right direction. I have a working setup with nginx, database, phpmyadmin and wp-cli but there's one thing I don't understand. Right now on my docker-compose file I have a named volume for Wordpress and a bind mount of `wp-content` directory for local development.

```yaml
volumes:
  - wordpress:/var/www/html
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

On many articles, blog posts and tutorials I've seen that it's a quite common practice to separate `wp-content` subdirectories bind mounts like this:

```yaml
volumes:
  - wordpress:/var/www/html
  - ./wp-content/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
  - ./wp-content/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
  - ./wp-content/mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
  - ./wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

What's the point? Where's the profit? Right now I'm quite happy with how it all works with a single `wp-content` directory bind mounted to my drive, but perhaps I'm missing some serious advantages here.

Pretty much everywhere I looked the only explanation I found was about the quite obvious difference between having only a named Wordpress volume and bind mounting some directories for development.

Comment: The only reasons I can see for doing this are (1) pointing sub-folders to different locations or (2) having more granular control over which sub-folders are mounted.

Comment: After working on my setup a little further I see that reason (2) makes a lot of sense. This way on my working directory I don't have `upgrade` folder and other useless generic stuff. Thanks.